# What is the sum of the least and the greatest positive four-digit multiples of 4 that can be written each using the digits 1, 2, 3 and 4 exactly once?

Tags: number-theory

What is the sum of the least and the greatest positive four-digit multiples of 4 that can be written each using the digits 1, 2, 3 and 4 exactly once?

There are 4!=24 arrangements of 4-digit numbers using 1,2,3,and 4 (no repeats allowed). The smallest one I found was 1324 and the largest was 4312. So 1324+4312=5636. Does this make sense or did I do this wrong?

Comment: It looks correct

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  If you were asked the same question with the digits $1$ to $9$ you would have a lot of possibilities to go through.  Remember the divisiblitiy test for $4$ says a number is divisible by $4$ if and only if the last two digits form a number divisible by $4$.  To get the largest you clearly want $98$ for the first two digits, then need the largest two digit number divisible by $4$ for the last two.  That is $76$ and the largest is $9876$.  For the smallest, you need $12$ for the first two and the smallest two digit number that does not contain $1$ or $2$ for the last two, which is $36$ and the smallest is $1236$